# Storing Golang JSON into Postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, struct, go

I want to store a certain struct into my database that has a JSON field within it.

```
type Comp struct {
    CompId               int64           `db:"comp_id" json:"comp_id"`
    StartDate            time.Time       `db:"start_date" json:"start_date"`
    EndDate              time.Time       `db:"end_date" json:"end_date"`
    WeeklySchedule       json.RawMessage `db:"weekly_schedule" json:"weekly_schedule"`
}
```

The schema for the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tr.Comp(
    comp_id                 SERIAL,
    start_date              timestamp NOT NULL,
    end_date                timestamp NOT NULL,
    weekly_schedule         json NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (comp_id)
);
```

I am using sqlx and lib/pq driver in my project and the following will not execute. Instead it panics saying there is a nil pointer. DB is a global `*sqlx.DB` struct

```
    tx := DB.MustBegin()

    compFixture := Comp{
        StartDate:            time.Now(),
        EndDate:              time.Now().AddDate(1, 0, 0),
        WeeklySchedule:       json.RawMessage([]byte("{}")),
    }
    _, err = tx.NamedExec(
        `INSERT INTO 
            Tr.Comp(comp_id, 
                start_date, end_date, weekly_schedule) 
            VALUES (DEFAULT, 
                :start_date, :end_date, :weekly_schedule)  
            RETURNING comp_id;`, compFixture)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal("Error creating fixture.", err)
    }
```

When I remove `weekly_schedule` from the schema and fixture things run fine. But for some reason, the when this field is included, the program panics. Any idea as to how I should define the `weekly_schedule` field in both my DB schema and Go struct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

sqlx has a type `JSONText` in `github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/types` that will do what you need

[doc](http://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/types#JSONText) for JSONText

Comment: recently renamed to `JSONText` see https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/commit/4301d72cf9192e9d0a830370e31323dce943e005

Comment: @HarryMoreno I updated my answer. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Hi, I edited the answer and put an example of the struct, because there are some people who do not read the answer much if they do not have a code example, but it helped me, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how clean of a solution this is but I ended up making my own data type `JSONRaw`. The DB driver sees it as a `[]btye` but it can still be treated like a json.RawMessage in the Go Code.

```
type JSONRaw json.RawMessage

func (j JSONRaw) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    byteArr := []byte(j)

    return driver.Value(byteArr), nil
}

func (j *JSONRaw) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    asBytes, ok := src.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return error(errors.New("Scan source was not []bytes"))
    }
    err := json.Unmarshal(asBytes, &j)
    if err != nil {
        return error(errors.New("Scan could not unmarshal to []string"))
    }

    return nil
}

func (m *JSONRaw) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return *m, nil
}

func (m *JSONRaw) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if m == nil {
        return errors.New("json.RawMessage: UnmarshalJSON on nil pointer")
    }
    *m = append((*m)[0:0], data...)
    return nil
}
```

This is copy paste reimplementation of `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` from the `encoding/json` library.

Answer (score 0):

from the go documentation:

```
json.RawMessage is a raw encoded JSON object. It implements Marshaler and Unmarshaler and can be used to delay JSON decoding or precompute a JSON encoding.
```

if you log.Printf("%#", colors) in the example provided at package json  json.RawMessage you can see that after unmarshalling the json object 'Point'-member isn't unmarshalled but left in []byte format until the color-format is fixed and 'Point' is unmarshalled explicitly.

Did you try something like unmarshal WeeklySchedule before putting it into the DB?