# Nested JSON result in Golang from Postgres

Tags: json, data-structures, go, struct, go-gin

I'm using [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) and [gorp](https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp)

**The SQL:**

```
SELECT p.project_id, p.name, 

COALESCE(NULLIF(json_agg(a.*)::TEXT, '[null]'), '[]')::JSON AS apps 

FROM project p LEFT JOIN app a USING (project_id) 

WHERE p.user_id=19 

GROUP BY p.project_id, p.name ORDER BY project_id
```

**The results:**
[image]

**Golang**

```
type Project struct {
    ID        int64           `db:"project_id, primarykey, autoincrement" json:"id"`
    UserID    int64           `db:"user_id" json:"user_id"`
    Name      string          `db:"name" json:"name"`
    Status    int             `db:"status" json:"status"`
    UpdatedAt int64           `db:"updated_at" json:"updated_at"`
    CreatedAt int64           `db:"created_at" json:"created_at"`
    Apps      json.RawMessage `json:"apps"`
}


func GetProjects(userID int64, page string) []Project {
    var projects []Project

    var err error
    _, err = db.GetDB().Select(&projects, "SELECT p.project_id, p.name, COALESCE(NULLIF(json_agg(a.*)::TEXT, '[null]'), '[]')::JSON AS apps FROM project p LEFT JOIN app a USING (project_id) WHERE p.user_id=$1 GROUP BY p.project_id, p.name ORDER BY project_id LIMIT 10 OFFSET $2", userID, page)
    fmt.Println("err", err)

    return projects
}
```

And returning the results using: `c.JSON(200, gin.H{"data": projects})`

It works if there's only one project

[image]

But if there's more than one project it gives the below error:

The error: `json: error calling MarshalJSON for type json.RawMessage: invalid character '"' after top-level value`

Any suggestions?

P.S: I'm a newbie in Golang

Comment: Rhe methods on json.RawMessage all take a pointer receiver. Did you try to add `Apps *json.RawMessage ...`?

Answer (score 4):

you can use this site http://json2struct.mervine.net/ to get right struct according to result. just copy select result, and generate your decent struct

or you can produce new type which have Project struct array:

```
type Projects []Project
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it work using this solution below from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25758711/689158)

> I don't know how clean of a solution this is but I ended up making my own data type `JSONRaw`. The DB driver sees it as a `[]btye` but it can still be treated like a `json.RawMessage` in the Go Code.
>
> This is a copy paste reimplementation of `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` from the encoding/json library.

```
//JSONRaw ...
type JSONRaw json.RawMessage

//Value ...
func (j JSONRaw) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    byteArr := []byte(j)

    return driver.Value(byteArr), nil
}

//Scan ...
func (j *JSONRaw) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    asBytes, ok := src.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return error(errors.New("Scan source was not []bytes"))
    }
    err := json.Unmarshal(asBytes, &j)
    if err != nil {
        return error(errors.New("Scan could not unmarshal to []string"))
    }

    return nil
}

//MarshalJSON ...
func (j *JSONRaw) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return *j, nil
}

//UnmarshalJSON ...
func (j *JSONRaw) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if j == nil {
        return errors.New("json.RawMessage: UnmarshalJSON on nil pointer")
    }
    *j = append((*j)[0:0], data...)
    return nil
}

//Project ....
type Project struct {
    ID        int64   `db:"project_id, primarykey, autoincrement" json:"id"`
    UserID    int64   `db:"user_id" json:"user_id"`
    Name      string  `db:"name" json:"name"`
    Status    int     `db:"status" json:"status"`
    UpdatedAt int64   `db:"updated_at" json:"updated_at"`
    CreatedAt int64   `db:"created_at" json:"created_at"`
    Apps      JSONRaw `json:"apps"`
}
```

[image]

But I was wondering if there's a *clean* way other than this?

Hope this also help others.

Comment: Hi, I wrote a blog a few weeks ago on handling JSON(B) coming from postgres. It's indeed about creating your own type to handle the JSON. In my case I converted it into a map[string]interface{}, which I suppose would  be handled by GIN correctly as well. http://coussej.github.io/2016/02/16/Handling-JSONB-in-Go-Structs/

Answer (score 0):

I used the below link
https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/using-postgresql-jsonb

and
http://json2struct.mervine.net/

to make it work .
I was struggling for long time and then realized that the struct did the trick.