# Golang Gorm working with slices and postgres' jsob field

Tags: json, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have a requirement to save either [] or a list with different integer values like [1, 7, 8]. These values can be anything between 1-31.

My struct for this field (DateOfMonth) is:

```
type Subscription struct {
    gorm.Model
    Enabled            bool    `gorm:"DEFAULT:True"`
    Deleted            bool    `gorm:"DEFAULT:False"`
    UserID             uint    `gorm:"not null"`
    Cap                int     `gorm:"DEFAULT:-1"`
    DateOfMonth        []int64 `gorm:"type:json default '[]'::json"`
}
```

Now, I need to read this value in an API and compare it with the current_date.

For this, I have tried:

```
type Result struct {
        ID               uint
        Email            string
        UniqueIdentifier string
        Cap              int
        DateOfMonth      []uint8
    }
    var subscriptions []Result
    if err := db.Table("users").Select("users.id, users.email, users.unique_identifier, subscriptions.cap, subscriptions.date_of_month").Joins("join subscriptions on users.id = subscriptions.user_id").Where("subscriptions.subscription_type_id=? and users.is_verified=? and subscriptions.enabled=?", subscription_type_id, true, true).Find(&subscriptions).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"error": true, "reason": "Subscribers not found!", "code": http.StatusBadRequest, "status": "failure"})
        return
    }
```

If I change `DateOfMonth      []uint8` to `DateOfMonth      []int64`, it gives error.
The value that I receive in this field is a list of byte values
For example, [] -> [91 93] and [6] -> [91 54 93]

If I do, `bytes.NewBuffer(s.DateOfMonth)`, I get the correct value but then I need to iterate over this slice to compare it with today's date. I have tried a lot of ways to get the actual value (6) in the loop (dom value) but to no avail.

```
// if len(s.DateOfMonth) > 0 {
        //  // date_of_month_new := binary.BigEndian.Uint64(date_of_month)
        //  todays_date_of_month := time.Now().Day()
        //  fmt.Println(todays_date_of_month) //, date_of_month, reflect.TypeOf(date_of_month))
        //  for _, dom := range s.DateOfMonth {
        //      fmt.Println("help", reflect.TypeOf(dom), dom, todays_date_of_month)
        //      // if dom == todays_date_of_month {
        //      //  fmt.Println("matching", dom, todays_date_of_month)
        //      // }
        //  }
        // }
```

I have even tried suggestions from various answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60092840/string-to-jsonb-with-gorm-and-postgres), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61073209/persisting-custom-set-data-type-using-gorm-golang), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36053251/nested-json-result-in-golang-from-postgres)

What am I missing here? Your help will be highly appreciated.

Some of the errors that I got:

```
invalid sql type DateOfMonth (slice) for postgres
Golang cannot range over pointer to slice
cannot range over bytes.NewBuffer(s.DateOfMonth) (type *bytes.Buffer)
sql: Scan error on column index 4, name "date_of_month": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *[]int
```

Comment: Please mention the error you get too

Comment: @VaibhavMishra added the errors

Comment: Why don't you use array types instead of JSON? The problem might be easier to solve that way

Comment: Array types are not supported in postgresql, and I don't want to create a relationship with that field. I just need to save some integer values for processing

Comment: I'm sorry @AnkitaGupta but it would be great if you could please add the errors with their stacktraces or the code that triggers them. The commented out code you have mentioned in the question is also unclear. What is it and it's purpose? And why is it commented? Also how you exactly tried the suggestions mentioned and their outcome? I am adding an answer with what understanding I have of your question right now though, hope it helps.

Comment: @VaibhavMishra I actually changed my table structure and now I save string (comma separated values) instead of the list and compare my value with that. What I was trying to do in the commented code was that I was iterating over the DateOfMonth key from the Result struct, which was ideally supposed to be a list of some integers. this list was getting saved from another api. This is commented because I was trying out a lot of suggestions which I found online and kept getting different errors, which I lost track of after some time.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Golang cannot range over pointer to slice
> ```

You are iterating over a pointer to a slice, instead of a slice. This means you will have to first de-reference your variable and then loop over it. Check out [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/PbZjFD-3_5h).

> ```
> cannot range over bytes.NewBuffer(s.DateOfMonth) (type *bytes.Buffer)
> ```

You cannot *range* over type `*bytes.Buffer`. You can instead access the bytes of the type by using the method `Buffer.Bytes()`. Check out [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/WRRpTPOORHH).

> ```
> sql: Scan error on column index 4, name "date_of_month": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *[]int
> ```

Judging by the error I'm guessing this happens when you use type `[]int64` while scanning `DateOfMonth`. One of the possibilities for this error is your database storing the values as `[]uint8` instead of `[]int64`.

> invalid sql type DateOfMonth (slice) for postgres

I'll try and update my answer after I am able to reproduce this error successfully.